# iText7 PDF taking time to generate

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to generate PDF in android using iText. PDF has been generated successfully but it is taking time to generate PDF as there are images added. Then I move my code of PDF generation from UI thread to background thread. After this, there comes an issue in PDF generation. Sometimes some pages don't load or images issues when generating PDF in the background.

Source Code

```
        val document = Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 100f, 60f)
        val pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,FileOutputStream(outputPdfPath))
        val event = HeaderFooterPageEvent();
        pdfWriter.pageEvent = event;
        document.isMarginMirroring = false;
        document.open()

        val reportBody = Paragraph()
        reportBody.font = Font(
            Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,
            16f,
            Font.NORMAL
        )
        reportBody.alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        document.add(getTitle("Prior Damage Check In"))
        document.add(createTables(reportBody, checkIn)) //for table creation
        document.add(
                addImage(
                    "image url",
                    PageSize.A4.getWidth() - document.leftMargin() -
                            document.rightMargin(),
                    PageSize.A4.getHeight() - document.topMargin() - document.bottomMargin() - 200,
                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER
                )
            )
```

Add Image method:

```
 private fun addImage(imagePath: String, width: Float, height: Float, alignment: Int): Image? {
    val image = Image.getInstance(imagePath)
    image.setAlignment(alignment)
    //image1.setWidthPercentage(50f);
    image.scaleToFit(width, height)
    return image
 }
```

There are 6 pages with images as above.

Please help how to solve this problem.

Comment: probably you did something wrong. Nobody knows because nobody saw your code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko have added source code for PDF generation

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"taking time to generate PDF"*? A few tenths seconds? A minute? Hours? Furthermore I don't see you closing the document. That can result in *"Sometimes some pages don't load or images issues"*. And you mention itext 7 but your code clearly is for itext 5 or earlier.

Comment: @blagae A different hat!

Comment: @mkl taking around 10 seconds. document has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that you save your pdf after background worker ended up his job ? 
You heard bout Monitors/critical sections in the concept of Multi Threading?

You should wait with saving PDF until all background workers will stop working in PDF.
Also take a notice, that every background worker (thread), could create PDF, not EDIT existing one, so you will always miss something, because PDF might be overwritten by one background worker, which can result in loosing data generated by another background workers (threads).